# Making a non-filled arrow with a tail in css

Tags: css

As title suggest - trying to make an arrow like this -> (obviously straight line ending where point ends)

Here is my current CSS:

```
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.4em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border-top: 0.1em solid;
  border-right: 0.1em solid;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow:after{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
  content: "";
  text-decoration: line-through;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Main problems at the moment is nothing is lining up. It needs to be centered with text

ie:

read more --->

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```css
:root{padding: 20px}
a{
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer
}
a:before,a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

a:before{
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  box-shadow: 8px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6),
             16px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4)
}
a:after{
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-top:   4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  right: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -4px
}
```

```html
<a>Read more</a>
```